# Angular 2 navigating in the different instances of the same component with different data to display

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a simple side menu in my Angular 2 applications which display a list of `classRoom`, each class Room has many users.

I navigate between the different instance with `routerLink`.

My problem is that when I click on the first item : -class Room number 1 I have no problem and the list of user are alright, but when I click on Class Room number 2 the data does not change, so the users displayed are the users of Class Room Number 2.

How can I tell Angular To re-render the component with the new data?
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE CODE EXAMPLE**

**side-menu.component.html**

```
<li *ngFor='let classRoom of classRooms'>
    <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['/app/users/', classRoom.name]">**Users**</a>
    </li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
</li>
```

**routes.ts**

```
....
{ path: 'app/users/:classroom', component: usersComponent},
```

So when i click on 'users' link, i call the users component, get classroom's name by route param and make a get request to get the users.

With the first class room no problem, but if i click on the 'users'link of the second classroom no change happend.

Comment: Yup, show the code ;-)

Comment: yes, i will add code exemple in few minutes

Comment: not sure but this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900212/in-angular-2-how-to-get-input-value-updated-inside-component

Answer (score 1):

I see you are loading `userComponent` in your route.ts. Can you try like below:

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="let classRoom of classRooms">
    <a [routerLink]="['/app/users/', classRoom.name]">
       <user-component></user-component>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no classrom component ! i have a classRooms object wich i get with http request, then i use *ngFor to display my classRooms name in the side menu, in each classRooms i would like to display the usersComponent

Comment: I can't do that, since a have to display the userCOmponent not in the side menu but in the main page

Answer (score 0):

Your routerLink needs a terminal route

```
[routerLink]="['parent', 'child', query.id]"
```

to understand it more clear, see this post
[see my question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639655/angular-2-how-to-use-same-child-component-with-different-data/42661012#42661012)