# Angular 2: How to use same child component with different data?

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a header that has menu consist of categories which they are the same component but different query.
The first call from parent to child is executed perfectly but if i navigateto another category from inside this child component i get error!

I know this is something wrong with the link when i navigate inside this child which make [routerLink] updated instantly.
Also if i navigate from category child component to login component which is separated component will give me the same error!

Note: Same question has been asked in this link with no answer

[Nacim Idjakirene Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614263/angular-2-navigating-in-the-diffrent-instances-of-the-same-component-with-differ)

**Router configuration**

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'landingpage', component: LandingpageComponent },
  {path: '', component: IndexComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'category/:cate', component: CategoryComponent },
        {path: 'post/:id', component: PostComponent },
        {path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent }
      ] },
  {path: 'login', component: LogginComponent }

];
```

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t4kN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved by me after a deep search. i saw the response of a person called

> **brandonroberts**: your router link is invalid and you either need to set a  terminal
>   route

and this solved my problem...

```
[routerLink]="['','category', cat.id]"
```